# Confusion about vim folding - how to disable?

Tags: vim, vi, folding

1. When I open the file it looks like this: 
   [image]
   or even this 
   [image]
2. When I open all folds, they are closed again when I navigated to another buffer and came back.
3. To be able to work with it, I have to apply `zR` each time when opening a buffer.

I have these set up in `.vimrc`:

```
set foldlevelstart=99
set foldlevel=99
```

Please point me on how to disable the folding, or at least making the navigation to another buffer not to close the opened ones.

Comment: When first starting vim, run `:set foldlevel` and `:set foldlevelstart` to see what they are set at.  My inital guess is that these values are getting reset somewhere.  When I add those values to my vimrc, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

You're not alone.

```
set nofoldenable    " disable folding
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't affect vimdiff. When vim creates a diff window it seems to override the `foldenable` option. The only workaround I've found is to set the `context` sub-option of `diffopt` to something really huge. eg: `set diffopt+=context:99999`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Perhaps something is overriding it.

Comment: it was [vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown#options). To disable folding by vim-markdown, use `let g:vim_markdown_folding_disabled=1`

Comment: @BenjaminGolder we have fixed that at: https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/pull/131

Comment: I like glts' solution below better: use 'zi' to toggle foldenable. One of the few BIG problem with vim is the sheer number of things to remember. Little things like 'zi' instead of 'foldenable' are god-sent!

Comment: doesnt seem to work for me :( python code is still folded.

Comment: The stock version of vim-awesome folded everything as well, BenjaminGolder's suggestion fixed it `let g:vim_markdown_folding_disabled=1`.

Comment: In my case this also required removing `~/.vim/view` files.

Answer (score 66):

The easiest way to disable (and enable) folding on the fly is `zi`.

`zi` is the normal mode command that toggles [`'foldenable'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27foldenable%27), just like `:set foldenable!`.

Mnemonic: "fold **i**nvert". See [`:h zi`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#zi).

Comment: The mnemonic for `z` -> `fold` is "z looks like it's folded"

Answer (score 46):

Add `set nofoldenable` to your ~/.vimrc to disable folding.

Comment: @Magnus: That's deliberately done by `vimdiff` to avoid showing lots of lines that are identical. The use case is different, so it's not affected by the `nofoldenable`. `zR` opens all folds; I do not know about a setting that disables folding in `vimdiff`. (As it's the one place where folding doesn't bother me.)

Answer (score 16):

[Here is an article](http://verens.com/2005/04/18/using-javascript-folds-in-vim/) which briefly and concisely sums up why folding is cool.  The one line reason is that folding makes navigating very large files a breeze.

If you want to leave folding enabled, and simply always start with all folds open, the vim wiki [tells how.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/All_folds_open_when_open_a_file)  The method of interest to you would probably be the autocommand method.

```
" Tweak the event and filetypes matched to your liking. 
" Note, perl automatically sets foldmethod in the syntax file
autocmd Syntax c,cpp,vim,xml,html,xhtml setlocal foldmethod=syntax
autocmd Syntax c,cpp,vim,xml,html,xhtml,perl normal zR
```

I would also recommend searching for custom folding methods for the language you use.  Simply googling "vim <insert language here> folding" should bring up a number of options.  Play around with the different options until you find a folding method you like.

Answer (score 5):

I have added this line to my `.vimrc` file cause I had the same issue:

`autocmd FileType * exe "normal zR"`

This command will be executed every time you open a file automatically. So you won't see the bug and the folding feature won't be lost too)

Answer (score 4):

Vim makes it amazingly hard to disable folding, especially when using vimdiff.
None of the above posted solutions worked for me, but this did (add to ~/.vimrc):

```
au WinEnter * set nofen
au WinLeave * set nofen
```

Comment: I just tested this and it works, but only if you also have `set nofoldenable`. Bizarre.

Comment: Woops. I spoke too soon. It still folds after you use `:diffobtain` in the git index of a file

Answer (score 3):

Just adding one more to make it complete to the point of discussion.

To enable code folding:

`:set foldenable` or in short, `:set fen`

To disable code folding:

`:set nofoldenable`  or in short, `:set nofen`

Once you enable codefolding, you will have all the commands like `zf,zo etc` at your wish according to the setting of `:set fdm=xxxx` where typical values are `expr,syntax,manual etc.`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, if I'm answering related question, but I found useful to display two files alongside with folding turned off with something like this:

```
vim "+set nofen" -O file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

I set `foldlevel=20`, `foldlevelstart=20` and I use `foldmethod=syntax`.
It's help me work with correct folding in vim.

`set nofoldenable` disable folding but sometimes I need it

[vim.wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/All_folds_open_when_opening_a_file)