# Folding of text in vim with Markdown syntax plugin

Tags: vim, plugins, syntax, markdown

I have a [Markdown syntax highlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1242) installed for Vim (MacVim). It's working well, but it automatically folds down headings, lists, etc.

Does anyone know how to disable the folding of sections *completely* with a plugin like this? I just want to be able to open Markdown documents without having every section collapsed every time...

Comment: I think this is duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017009/confusion-about-vim-folding-how-to-disable

Comment: You're totally right. Didn't find that searching before (somehow)...

Comment: Sorry - this previous question answers mine:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017009/confusion-about-vim-folding-how-to-disable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this question popped up first in my search, I'll duplicate zeuxcg's answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017009/confusion-about-vim-folding-how-to-disable):

```
set nofoldenable    " disable folding
```